# Why is app.urls not found?(Django Python)

Tags: python, django, backend

I’m making my first django based backend server and I registered the urls for each app like

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('backfo/', include('backfo.urls')),
    path('commun/', include('commun.urls')),
    path('starts/', include('starts.urls')),
    path('travleres/', include('travleres.urls')),
    path('starts/', include('starts.urls')),
    path('new/', include('new.urls')),
    path('joint/', include('joint.urls')),
]
```

Then I get this error in cmd saying ->

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backfo.urls'
```

I don’t get what went wrong and if you need more code I’ll post it on.

Comment: can you show your project structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In settings.py add module in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: I already did that

Comment: add project name "project_name.backfo.urls"

Comment: this shouldn't be a problem, I'm using apps that have no models and are not listed in installed_apps, but still I can include urls from them